# Cuckoo Search with Levy Flight in Java

Tags: algorithm, optimization, machine-learning

I'm trying to learn concept about cuckoo search algorithm. Honestly, i'm learning cuckoo search using java source code. we know that cuckoo search using levy distribution for random walk. I have java source code impelements cuckoo search optimation , but i'm doubt that source code using levy distribution. Can anyone help me to inspect wheteher my source code using levy distribution or not?.

this is method that implements random walk..

```
public CSSolution randomWalk (OptimizationProblem prob, String distribution) {
        int n = prob.getNumVar(); //2
        // creates a neighborhood of size 1 times the scaling factor
        double distanceSquared = Math.pow(rand.nextDouble() * 
           prob.getScalingFactor(),2);
       System.out.println("distance Squared : "+distanceSquared);
        // creates an ArrayList from 0 to n-1 (for indexing purposes only)
        ArrayList<Integer> varIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            varIndices.add(i, i);
        }
        ArrayList<Double> vars = this.getVars();
        CSSolution newSol = new CSSolution(this.numVars);
        newSol.initializeWithNull();
        ArrayList<Double> newVars = newSol.getVars();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            /* Chooses a random variable index from the indices
             * of the remaining/unwalked variables. */
            int index = rand.nextInt(varIndices.size());
            // Finds the variable value that this index corresponds to.
            int varIndex = varIndices.get(index);
 //               System.out.println("varIndicesSize:"+varIndices.size()+" index: "+index+" varIndex: "+varIndex);
            double curVar = vars.get(varIndex);

            // use correct distribution to generate random double [0,1)
            double r;
            if (distribution == "weibull"){
                r = weibull.random(1.5, 1, new uniform());
            }
            else if(distribution == "levy"){
                r = 0.0;
            }
            else
                r = rand.nextDouble();
            // alters this variable coefficient by adding a random step between (-distance,distance)
            double distance = Math.sqrt(distanceSquared);
                System.out.println("distance : "+distance+" distance Squared : "+distanceSquared);
            double varStep = r*distance*2-distance;
            double newVar = curVar + varStep;
//          System.out.println("x"+varIndex+" : "+curVar+" to "+newVar);
                newVars.set(varIndex, newVar);
            // removes the variable that has already been visited
            varIndices.remove(index);
            // updates distance for next for loop
            distanceSquared -= Math.pow(varStep, 2);

        }
//        System.out.println("");
        return newSol;
    }
```

source code : https://github.com/cloudrave/Optimizer

Comment: i'm change the code, there's no "else if(distribution == 'levy')" in the original code

Comment: The posted code differs from the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/cloudrave/Optimizer/blob/master/src/solutions/CSSolution.java).